# strange behavior when updating matrix

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, updating

```
import numpy as np

X_mini=np.array([[   4, 2104,    1],
   [   1, 1600,    3],
   [   3, 2400,    100]])

def feature_normalization(X):

    row_length=len(X[0:1][0])

    for i in range(0, row_length):
        if not X[:,i].std()==0:

            temp=(X[:,i]-X[:,i].mean())/X[:,i].std()
            print(temp)
            X[:,i]=temp



feature_normalization(X_mini)
print(X_mini)
```

outputs:

```
[ 1.06904497 -1.33630621  0.26726124]
[ 0.209937   -1.31614348  1.10620649]
[-0.72863911 -0.68535362  1.41399274]
[[ 1  0  0]
 [-1 -1  0]
 [ 0  1  1]]
```

my question is, why does not X_mini (after applying feature_normalization) correspond to what is being printed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array holds values of integer type (probably int64).
When fractions are inserted into it, they're converted to int.

You can explicitly specify the type of an array you create:

```
X_mini = np.array([[ 4.0,  2104.0,  1.0],
       [ 1.0,  1600.0,  3.0],
       [ 3.0,  2400.0,  100.0]], dtype=np.float128)
```

You can also convert an array to another type using `numpy.ndarray.astype` ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy-ndarray-astype)).